# Recursive attempt to load library - What does that mean in android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sip, voip, rtp

I am working with android SIP for VoIP. The application is receiving calls successfully. However, initiation of a call is having some bugs.

There is no error in the logs but info says:

`" I/art: Thread[1,tid=23775,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4f07800,peer=0x759512e0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/librtp_jni.so" "`

Can anyone explain what is the problem and how could we possible solve it?

Comment: Which Android version/device did you face this problem? Are you building as part of ROM or Application ?

Comment: Android 5.0
Its an application

Comment: a indentical but unaswered question with the same problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550513/android-sip-recursive-attempt-to-load-library-system-lib-librtp-jni-so

Answer (score 2):

That warning originates when you attempt to load a native library while it was already loaded. You can safely ignore this warning as nothing happens except for printing that warning.