# Android SIP - recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/librtp_jni.so"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, sip, voip

I see above log message when initiating SIP call from Android app using Android SIP SDK.
Here's the line which causes it:

```
mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfileLocal, mSipProfilePeer, listener, 20);
```

I don't think there's anything wrong (at least related to the above message) in that line.
But anyway, after that method is called, I see

```
recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/librtp_jni.so"
```

And SIP call never gets established. Also, I don't receive any error messages/exceptions - nothing.
Have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

Btw, according to my investigation, "recursive attempt to load library" doesn't affect functionality. On majority of devices SIP calls work for me.
But on Samsung Tab A (2016) I see exactly same behavior as described above.